# Software Auto Updater in Java

Tags: java

I'm developing a software which I will patch early & often, so I'm looking into an autoupdater made in Java.

If I google "auto updater java" it gives me the auto updater for Java, not software in general.

EDIT: Java Web Start and JNLP are not viable options since they're buggy and not reliable at all (or such is the general opinion).

Comment: why dont't you write it your own? shouldn't be that complicated...

Comment: I guess you're right, but I just wanted to safe some time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Java Web Start. It will automatically update your application, when you have an updated version. If properly configured. JNLP works well.
Check out the [JnlpDownloadServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) Guide.

Also Check out [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)'s [site](http://pscode.org/jws/).

With jnlp, you can

1. Add a custom icon.
2. Install a shortcut on desktop.
3. Add application in the start menu.
4. Add a custom splash screen.

Comment: Am I missing something? I was under impression that JWS is really unreliable?

Comment: @Howie - I think you are missing something.  JWS / JNLP are probably *more* reliable than some mechanism that you implement yourself.  :-)